# Insert value from one array to another and keep their keys

Tags: php, arrays, merge, key

I have 2 Arrays :

```
Array
(
    [1] => image1
    [4] => image2
)

Array
(
    [0] => title 1
    [2] => title 2
    [3] => title 3
)
```

I just want to merge these arrays and KEEP their key (`[1] => image1` will also be at `[1]` in the new array)

Any idea please ? Thanks !

Comment: What should happen in case of a key conflict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work :)

```
foreach ($array2 as $key => $value)
{
    $array1[$key] = $value;
}
```

The keys & values from array2 will be appended at the end. If your array is just numeric, you can bring it to the right order with [`array_sort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php).

Comment: Yeah and bear in mind that the keys might conflict. If you don't have that, don't worry, otherwise you'll need to handle this exception seperatly

Answer (score 1):

I think this function works. You have to use only numeric keys tough

```
$array1;
$array2;

array_weird_merge($array1, $array2){
    $result = array();

    //get the keys of each array
    $keys1 = array_keys($array1);
    $kesy2 = array_keys($array2);

    //get the max keys of the 2 arrays
    $max = max($key1, $key2);
    //we go trough all the possible values
    for ($i=0; $i<$max;$i++){
        //if the array 1 has an element in the
        //$i position, we put it in the result
        //if not, then we check in the second
        //array. (we give priority to the array
        //that comes first)
        if(isset($array1[$i])){
            $result[$i] = $array1[$i];
        }else if(isset($array2[$i])){
            $result[$i] = $array2[$i];
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: "Values in the input array with numeric keys will be renumbered with incrementing keys starting from zero in the result array. " (php manual)

Comment: I was editing the answer as I saw my mistake right after posting it, you guys are correct.

Comment: Nope, still not it. It will just add the 'overhanging' part of the longer array. See the first comment from cb in the manual on array operators!

Comment: @adnontheline: you might misread something, I linked you a demo.

Comment: @hakre, where can I see the demo ? I tested it with the array of the OP and it didn't work. Daniel, that's a nice solution for non-numerical arrays to keep the order, like it. For simple numeric arrays like the OPs I guess my solition is a bit nicer ;)